# Script to estimate itinerary duration based on traffic

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

To get to work I can take two different buses. I would need a script that tells me which one is the fastest, based on the current traffic.

Is it possible, with Google Maps API, to get a duration estimation of an itinerary, provided a list of waypoints?

Comment: For the downvoter: how could I make the question less broad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [DirectionsRequest](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en#DirectionsRequest) object has a `durationInTraffic` property.

> Whether or not we should provide trip duration based on current traffic conditions. Only available to Maps API for Work customers.

As you can read from the documentation, this is not available in the free API version.

Comment: Ok. Then it's impossible to get that for free, right?

Comment: Well... no. At least not with the Google Maps API.